# How can I resolve <could not resolve type> message on operator "=" for deque<int>?

Tags: c++, deque

I have passed a deque variable into a function by reference and am trying to set it equal to a local deque variable of the same type.

In main I define:

```
vector<vector<deque<int>>> memo_r (max_city, vector<deque<int>>((1<<(max_city))-1));
```

Then in my function:

```
double Held_Karp( ... , vector<vector<deque<int>>> &memo_r, ... ){
  deque<int> temp_route;
  temp_route.push_front(0);
  memo_r[x][y] = temp_route;
}
```

But the values from temp_route are not placed in memo_r[x][y]. When debugging i get the message `<could not resolve type>`. Why might this be? What steps can I do to fix/debug this problem?

Thanks!

All Related Code:

```
double Held_Karp(int pos, long long unsigned city_bit, int max_city, const vector<vector<double>>&graph, vector<vector<double>> &memo, vector<vector<deque<int>>> &memo_r, deque<int> &deque_reference) {
    if (city_bit == (1<<(max_city))-1) {
        //printf("%d 1^\n",pos);
        return graph[pos+1][0+1];
    }

    if (memo[pos][city_bit] != -1) {
        //printf("%d 2^\n",pos);
        return memo[pos][city_bit];
    }

    //Ensure some "lowest_result" is accepted
    double lowest_result = numeric_limits<double>::max();
    deque<int> temp_route;
    for (int i = 0; i < max_city; i++) {
        if (i != pos && (city_bit & (1 << i)) == 0){
            deque<int> lower_deque_local;
            //printf("%d !\n",pos);
            double new_lower = graph[pos+1][i+1] + Held_Karp(i, city_bit | (1 << i), max_city, graph, memo, memo_r, lower_deque_local);
            if (lowest_result > new_lower) {
                lowest_result = new_lower;
                temp_route = lower_deque_local;
                temp_route.push_front(i);
                //Consider replace deque_reference with better lower_deque
                //Add the node you just came from
                deque_reference = lower_deque_local;
                deque_reference.push_front(i);
            }
            //lowest_result = min(lowest_result, graph[pos+1][i+1] + Held_Karp(i, city_bit | (1 << i), max_city, graph, memo));
        }
    }
    memo[pos][city_bit] = lowest_result;
    memo_r[pos][city_bit] = temp_route;
    //printf("%d 3^\n",pos);
    return lowest_result;
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    vector<vector<double>> Graph (1000, vector<double>(1000 , 0));

    //Set to max_city - 0 not used
    int max_city = fillGraph(Graph,argv[1]);
    vector<vector<double>> memo (max_city, vector<double>((1<<(max_city))-1, -1));
    vector<vector<deque<int>>> memo_r (max_city, vector<deque<int>>((1<<(max_city))-1));
    deque<int> route;

    clock_t tStart = clock();

    double time = Held_Karp(0, 1, max_city, Graph, memo, memo_r, route);

    //Print out
    printf("OPTIMAL TOUR LENGTH: %f\n", time);

    printf("TSP TOUR:\n");
    //printf("1\n");
    int size = (int)route.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        printf("%d\n",(route.back()+1));
        route.pop_back();
    }
    //printf("1\n");

    printf("Total Time Elapsed: %fs\n", (double)(clock() - tStart)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC);

}
```

When I walk though the execution in Xcode I can see the data is not copied into memo_r[x][y] from temp_route. The index where the data should be shows, but is displayed in the IDE as empty. When I click 'more info' I see the `<could not resolve type>` message.

Comment: Where are you getting the error?  Does the code compile?

Comment: Yes, it does. But when I walk though it (in Xcode). I can see that the value is not copied into memo_r[x][y].

Comment: Show all of your relevant code or a MCVE.  Otherwise there's not enough info.

Comment: No problem, I have updated. Thanks for being patient!

Comment: Does the program work outside the debugger?  Perhaps only the debugger is having an issue.

Comment: Wow, I think you are right. When I step though in gdb the copy seems to be working fine. The code is for Held_Karp (as you can see) and finds the best time just fine, but I am working on traceback now.

Anyways, it seems my issues are elsewhere in the code. Xcodes IDE must be acting weird for some reason, makes debugging harder. Oh well.

Thanks!